A question related to Operator Norm : $\Vert F \Vert =\Vert \tilde F \Vert$

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Normed Linear Spaces and $Z$ be a closed subspace of $X$.
(a) Let $F\in BL(X,Y)$ and $Z\subset Z(F)$. The map $\tilde F:X/Z \to Y$ given by $\tilde F(x+Z)=F(x),x\in X $, is well defined, $\tilde F\in BL(X/Z,Y)$ and $\Vert \tilde F\Vert =\Vert F \Vert$.


(b) If $\tilde F\in BL(X/Z,Y)$ and we let $F(x)=\tilde F(x+Z)$ for $x\in X$, then $F\in BL(X,Y)$ and $\Vert F \Vert =\Vert \tilde F\Vert$.

I have proved the well definedness and the other neacessary things what the questions have asked except $\Vert F \Vert=\Vert \tilde F \Vert$. However, I have outlined the proof in the following way:
$$ \Vert \tilde F \Vert=inf\{\alpha >0 : \Vert \tilde F(x+Z) \Vert \le\alpha \Vert x+Z\Vert_Q, \forall x+Z\in X/Z\}=inf \{\alpha >0 :\Vert F(x) \Vert\le\Vert x+Z\Vert_Q, \forall x+Z\in X/Z\}=inf\{\alpha >0 : \Vert F(x)\Vert \le \alpha \Vert x\Vert, \forall x\in X\}=\Vert F\Vert. $$
Here, $\Vert .\Vert_Q$ is the norm on the quotient space.
Please check the above implications and provide your valuable suggestions whether I am on the right tracK. Thank you, beforehand.

Very awkward notation. Just say $F : X \to Y$ bounded linear and $\tilde{F}$ the quotient map through the kernel (you can prove that your $Z$ can be taken maximal easily). The norm involves a sup of $\|F(x)\|/\|x\|$ and trivially thus the elements in the kernel do not have to be factored in. In fact in most cases we do not even differentiate with $\tilde{F}$, we just conflate the notation to just saying $F$, as a map $X \to Y$ or $X / \ker F \to Y$.

Yeah, the notation is a little bit unusual, all credits go to my textbook for choosing this notation. Thank you. I got your point. @TheAlertGerbil

You're welcome. Books can choose verbose notation to help understanding for the student by being explicit, but in regular communication between those that are already familiar, it hampers the flow of ideas.
